# border-radius css property doesnt work in windows live client

Tags: css, html-email

Actually i am creating an HTML Email template everything works but '**border-radius**' doesnt 
work in windows live client, although it works in browsers and gmail also.

```
<div style='width: 700px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Geneva,   
        sans-serif; font-size: 12px;border: 1px Solid #094375;border-radius:
        6px 6px 6px 6px; -moz-border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;   
        -webkit-border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;'> 
</div>
```

In the above div border-radius css property is defined but it is not working in windows live client, If any one have solution then please share
(want to give round corner to the div),
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: try making that `solid` instead of `Solid`.

Comment: @xFortyFourx: still not working

Comment: @VinaySinha oh, I'm sorry, I thought it was the border that's not working, border-radius is not working probably because their HTML rendering engine is old which doesn't support border-radius.

Comment: @Boaz: gone through the link, it seems like only image is the option to put round corner that works in every email clients

Comment: @xFortyFourx:Thanks for ur reply :)

Comment: @VinaySinha Email-clients are notoriously incompatible with many CSS properties. So images are a common solution in email templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Border radius is one of the many CSS attributes not widely supported in email. [Here](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) is some CSS email support reference.